# How do I get this code to count and sort the names given above? (Beginner)

Tags: python, list

```
name = ["Safi", "Safi", "Safi", "Umaima", "Arsalah", "Farooq", "Ben", "Ben"]
list = ["Safi", "Safi", "Safi", "Umaima", "Arsalah", "Farooq", "Ben", "Ben"]
a = input("What would you like to know about the following list?")

if a == "Sort this list":
  print (list.sort())

if a == "What is the Number of "+a+"'s":
  print(list.count(+a))
else:
  print("I don't understand")
```

The code doesn't want to accept the input from the user as it just skips the user's input and doesn't integrate it.

Comment: Its simply because your input doesn't exactly match the string. You need to use `lower` to skip uppercases

Comment: Edits: Added a little more space to make the code easier on the eyes. Removed the last sentence, as it's meaning was unclear. Please use the edit-button below the question to update it and add more info yourself, if you think it might make the question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is the fact that sort() function does not return anything, so you have to print the list after sorting it :

```
name = ["Safi", "Safi", "Safi", "Umaima", "Arsalah", "Farooq", "Ben", "Ben"]
list = ["Safi", "Safi", "Safi", "Umaima", "Arsalah", "Farooq", "Ben", "Ben"]
a = input("What would you like to know about the following list?")
if a == "sort":
    list.sort()
    print (list)
if a == "count":
    keyword = input("Which string to you want to count ?")
    print (list.count(keyword)) #I think you want to count the occurence of the input word
```